# How do I pass the grains of one minion to another?

Tags: salt-stack

I am using Salt to configure a number of servers. Two of them are assigned the role of a DNS server and configured using the [`dnsmasq-formula`](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/dnsmasq-formula). Others have various roles, such as `gitlab-server`, which are defined in the pillar.

Here's how this is configured:

```
/srv/salt/top.sls
---
base:
  'roles:dns-server':
    - match: pillar
    - dnsmasq
  'roles:gitlab-server'
    - gitlab

/srv/pillar/top.sls
---
{% import_yaml "roles.yaml" as r %}
base:
{% if 'dns-server' in r[grains['id']] %}
    - dns.dnsserv
{% endif %}

/srv/pillar/dns/dnsserv.sls
---
dnsmasq:
  ...
  hosts:
    domain.name:
      git: <GIT_SERVER_IP>
  ...

/srv/pillar/roles.yaml
---
'minion1-id':
  - role1
  - role2
'minion2-id':
  - role3
  - role4
# and so on
```

Right now the `<GIT_SERVER_IP>` is hardcoded. I would rather like to query the minions, find the one with the right role and extract its IP address programatically.

When `/srv/pillar/dns/dnsserv.sls` is processed, it is processed with the info available to the minion with the role "dns-server". By loading `roles.yaml` inside of `dnsserv.sls` I can manage to get the minion ID of the gitlab-server (with some very ugly code). But how can I get its IP from this file?

I have seen mentions of the salt mine, but have not really found a complete example how to use this functionality.

This question may well be an example of an XY problem. If so, an example of the "proper way" would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To pass grains or pillar from one minion to another, you need to use "salt mine" (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/mine/). The topic is not simple but briefly:

- define a new mine_function available to your minions, like

```
mine_functions:
  grains:
    grains.items: []
```

- then use it in your state with mine.get https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mine.html#salt.modules.mine.get

I recommend you to first try mine.get on command line to see if you're able to retrieve your data, before starting to write a state.